# Seeding Models from a CSV file with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, csv, eloquent

I'm new to laravel, so warning in advance that this might be a no-brainer.

I'm trying to seed a couple of Models with a CSV file. The file contans a list of names and locations of stores. Let's say it looks like this:

```
StoreName, City, State
store1, Philadelphia, PA
store2, Philadelphia, PA
store3, Altoona, PA
store4, Portland, OR
store5, Portland, OR
```

At the end, the result will be a City Model and a State Model. City would have columns for the name of the city, state, and total stores in that city:

```
id, name, state, total
1, Philadelphia, PA, 2
2, Altoona, PA, 1
3, Portland, OR, 2
```

And the State Model will have columns for name, and total stores in that state:

```
id, name, total
1, PA, 3
2, OR, 2
```

I then have a hasMany relation within the State Model:

```
class State extends Model
{
    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(City::class, 'state', 'name');
    }
}
```

This relationship defines the 'state' column from the State Model as the foreign key, and the 'name' column from City as the local key.

I am wondering if this relationship could be better. Is there a way that I could build the City Model with an attribute of 'state_id', and then have that match the State Model's 'id' attribute? Would this make for a performance increase for when I call `App\State::find(#)->cities`?

Or, is there anything else I need to do to define 'state' as the foreign key for the State Model?

Also, is there a simpler way of extracting the CSV file to multiple separate models with Eloquent, rather than a foreach loop through each record in the CSV?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In-fact this is not related to laravel, this question is related to database design more than laravel.

> Is there a way that I could build the City Model with an attribute of 'state_id', and then have that match the State Model's 'id' attribute?

Yes, you can use an integer or the state id, and it's more preferable as comparing numbers is faster than string-based comparison.

> Also, is there a simpler way of extracting the CSV file to multiple separate models with Eloquent, rather than a foreach loop through each record in the CSV?

I don't think so, you have to do it one way or another, but you can use array functions to make it easier to read and a bit shorter ..

e.g to extract the states from the csv

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));

$states = array_unique(array_column($csv,2));
$cities = array_unique(array_column($csv,1));
```